# How to save JSON response in dynamodb in GO

Tags: json, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I want to save a JSON response in aws-dynamodb, I am using [aws-dynamodb-sdk](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb). What I'm currently doing is:

```
func (e *DB) saveToDynamodb(data map[string]interface{}){
params := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    Item: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "Key": {
            M: data,
        },
    },
    TableName: aws.String("Asset_Data"),
}
resp, err := e.dynamodb.PutItem(params)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

But as you can see **data** is of **map[string]interface{}** type while the expected type is **map[string]*AttributeValue** that's why giving compilation error.

Is there any workaround to save a json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put JSON in aws-dynamodb we first need to iterate through each attribute of JSON struct and convert it to dynamodb.AttributeValue in the following manner:

```
func (e *DB) saveToDynamodb(data map[string]interface{}){
var vv=make(map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue)

for k,v:=range data{
    x:=(v.(string)) //assert string type
    xx:=&(x)
    vv[k]=&dynamodb.AttributeValue{S: xx,}
}
//s:=data["asset_id"].(string)
params := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    Item: vv,
    TableName: aws.String("Asset_Data"), // Required
}
resp, err := e.dynamodb.PutItem(params)

if err != nil {
    // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
    // Message from an error.
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

// Pretty-print the response data.
fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to put json into DynamoDB is to use the helper functions.

```
func ExampleMarshal() (map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue, error) {                                                                                                    
  type Record struct {                                                                                                     
    Bytes   []byte                                                                                                         
    MyField string                                                                                                         
    Letters []string                                                                                                       
    Numbers []int                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                        

  r := Record{                                                                                                             
    Bytes:   []byte{48, 49},                                                                                               
    MyField: "MyFieldValue",                                                                                               
    Letters: []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"},                                                                                 
    Numbers: []int{1, 2, 3},                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                        
  av, err := dynamodbattribute.Marshal(r)
  return map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{"object":av}, err
}
```

Comment: where is dynamodbattribute defined?

Comment: [package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use type assertion in this case.

Give it a try to this:

```
func (e *DB) saveToDynamodb(data map[string]interface{}){
  params := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
      Item: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
          "Key": {
              M: data.(map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue), // assert interface to *dynamodb.AttributeValue
          },
      },
      TableName: aws.String("Asset_Data"),
  }
  resp, err := e.dynamodb.PutItem(params)

  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err.Error())
      return
  }
  fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: you can't do that it's invalid type assertion because data is not an interface.